# Infinite chinese remainder theorem for $\Bbb{Z}/p, p \text{ prime}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, ideals, integers, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let $X = \prod_{p=2 \\ \text{prime}}^{\infty}\Bbb{Z}/p$.  Let $\phi : \Bbb{Z} \to X$ be the natural projection in each component.

Then for any $x \in X$, there exists an integer $y$ such that $\phi(y) = x$ by infinite Chinese remaindering?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adele_ring for a (much more complicated) construction that might be similar to the kind of thing you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No: Take $x = \prod_p x(p)$ with $x(2) = 1$ and all other $x(p) = 0$. If $x = \phi(y)$, then $y$ would have to be nonzero but divisible by every prime $p > 2$.

Answer (score 3):

No:

$X$ is obviously uncountable. How are you going to map onto it from $\mathbb Z$?